# Remove text formatting and keep only text in a Numbered/ Word list

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word file with a numbered list with some applied formatting for the text.

I need to remove the formatting of the text and keep text only but keeping the list numbering intact.

How I can I achieve this using VBA by iterating through the entire list with one item at a time.. pls advice.

BTW I'm a novice in using VBA but have a little knowledge of the basics.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
Public Sub Iterate_Paragraphs()
    Dim Paragraph As Word.Paragraph
    iParCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    Dim sMypar As String

        For J = 1 To iParCount
            sMypar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text
            sMypar.Copy
            sMypar.PasteSpecial datatype:=wdPasteText
            ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text = sMypar
        Next J

End Sub
```

Comment: Public Sub Iterate_Paragraphs()
    Dim Paragraph As Word.Paragraph
    iParCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    Dim sMypar As String
    
For J = 1 To iParCount
    sMypar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text
    sMypar.Copy
    sMypar.PasteSpecial datatype:=wdPasteText
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text = sMypar
Next J
    
End Sub

Comment: Hi braX...  this is my first time on a forum... pls excuse my awkwardness

Comment: `sMyPar` is a `String`, there's no method to use from it. In addition to providing code, you also have to explain what problem do you have with it. (Is there an error? Or it's just not doing what you want?)

Comment: Just a guess, try just `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text` in the loop. It might just remove the formatting but not sure about keeping the list number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr. Wu. I'm running into a compile error... invalid qualifier inside the loop

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the current version of your code? @animem

Comment: ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text is not working

Comment: So the error occured at this line? Did you delete the 3 lines above? (Those `sMyPar...` lines)

Comment: yes..I have removed the 3 lines, no error but it is not removing the formatting

Comment: I do think there's a way to deal with this without using `Selection` but perhaps look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60826332/remove-direct-formatting-to-ms-word-document-with-vba-macro) and try it out.

Comment: Tried the above answer by selecting .. but it's not clearing the formatting. Copying the text and pasting it again using paste special -unformatted text is the only thing working..

Comment: The formatting could be from the paragraph style then since clearing direct formatting don't work so perhaps use `Selection.ClearFormatting` instead. @animem

Comment: Tried it... but not working. Thanks for looking into Mr. Wu

Comment: Is there a standardized `formatting` you are looking for? If so then simply apply the formatting directly into the `Paragraph.Range`? Formatting either comes from style formatting (which then you have to modify the style properties) or directly formatting so if directly formatting dont work, try look into the style its using

Answer (score 0):

I'd refer you to this article

https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010248_Converting_Automatic_Numbering_to_Manual_Numbering.html

Which presents the following code

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
```

Comment: Thank you.. will try

Answer (score 0):

To remove formatting, in addition to `ActiveDocument.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToTex` you need to clear formatting and change the style for all text to the normal or body text style.